# Trouble getting started with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been trying to implement a mod-rewrite to clean up my urls. I have never done this before.

The following is an example of one of my urls:

```
http://www.example.com/listings.php?category=Accident%20and%20Crash%20Repairs
```

The file **listings.php** is at the root level of my site.

I have tested that mod-rewrite is enabled on my server and have found it to be working correctly.

Starting with a blank file I am trying to create a .htaccess file to rewrite my urls. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /listings.php?category=$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/listings.html$ /listings.php?category=Accident%20and%20Crash%20Repairs [L]
```

In the next example I was just trying to get a part the url to change, loosely based on an answer to another query on stack overflow.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule    ^lineage/?$    listings.php   [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried a lot more combinations and followed a few tutorials. Needless to say nothing has worked.

If possible I would like the url to appear as:

```
http://www.example.com/listings/accident-and-crash-repairs
```

but if not I would settle for not seeing the variable at all.

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong or help me work this out in any way?

Many thanks.

Comment: What happened if you loaded `http://www.example.com/lineage/` or `http://www.example.com/listings.html` or `http://www.example.com/Accident%20and%20Crash%20Repairs.html`? Did you get a 404-page?

Comment: @Gerben Thanks for commenting. No 404 page. Page looks fine just without any results.

Comment: So `http://www.example.com/listings.php?category=Accident%20and%20Crash%20Repairs` loads your page fine with all the results?

Comment: @anubhava Yeah works great. Its probably not build very well as a system but I am only learning. Only trouble is re-writing the urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+listings/[^\?\s%20]+\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^listings/([^-]+)-([^-]+)(.*)$ listings/$1\%20$2$3 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+listings/[^\?\s%20]+\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^listings/([^-]+)/?$ listings.php?category=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(category)=([^%20]+)%20([^%20]+)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(listings\.php)/?$ $1?%1=%2-%3%4 [R=302,L,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=([^\s%20]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(listings)\.php/?$ $1/%1? [R=302,L,NC,NE]
```

Once this recursion based rules in place a URI of `/listings/accident-and-crash-repairs` will be forwarded to `/listings.php?category=accident%20and%20crash%20repairs`

And a URI of `/listings.php?category=accident%20and%20crash%20repairs` will be externally redirected to `/listings/accident-and-crash-repairs`.

Once you verify it's working change `R=302` to `R=301`.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer. I am having a look at it now. Will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Having looked at your answer and altered my .htaccess file to fit, unfortunately I am still unable to get mod_rewrite to work. A site redirect 301 works fine when added to the file but not the mod_rewrite. Strange! My host company insists that mod_rewrite is enabled across all their servers. Thank you very much for your answer anyway.

Comment: What URI did you that didn't work? Can you give some details like what didn't work? Did you get 404 or what> Finally please post your current .htaccess in your question.

Comment: If I enter the url http://www.example.com/listings/accident-and-crash-repairs in the address bar then I am brought to the correct page. So yes this answer is correct. I was mistaken sorry. However I think my issue has now changed slightly. I need to get the clicked link to bring me to the page with the rewritten url. At present it still takes me to http://www.example.com/listings.php?category=accident%20and%20crash%20repairs

Comment: Oh that should be easy to handle. Just add `R=301` in the last RewriteRule above (see edited answer).

Comment: Thanks for that but I think it may be the wrong way round for my needs. With the R=301 in place, when I type example.com/listings/accident-and-crash-repairs in my browser, the url I see is http://www.example.com/listings.php?category=Accident%20and%20Crash%20Repairs

Comment: Yes that is the expected behavior by adding `R=301`. Do you want a this URL in the browser `example.com/listings.php?category=Accident%20and%20Crash%20Repairs` to become: `example.com/listings/accident-and-crash-repairs`?

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. Now I just have to work out how it is working :0)

Comment: Sorry, another quick question for you. If the query has no spaces (%20) in it I get the following error: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects. How do I allow for this?